# Build a nomogram for a semi-parametric cox model: help to find the (best) time point for prediction

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival, cox-model

I'm using R 3.6 software. I try to build a nomogram for my survival data but I don't understand how can I choose the survival time point prediction. I have a maximum survival time of 3500 days. If I delete `time.inc` or if I put 8000, 200 or whatever, it plots always the same nomogram. Thus my question is easy: what is the optimal time for a prediction with a maximum follow up of ~3500 days? I suppose the package does it automatically but my research to find out the chosen time for the prediction were unsuccessful (I've read a lot papers, including those of F. Harrell)! Hence my request.

Here the lines code. It is for a semi-parametric Cox model.

```
summary(data$time_in_day)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   52.0   715.5  1030.0  1173.0  1472.5  3438.0 

library(rms)
library("SvyNom")
library(survey)
dd = datadist(data)
options(datadist='dd')

phmodel <- cph(Surv(time_in_day, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 , 
                 data=data,x=TRUE,y = TRUE, surv = TRUE,
                 se.fit = TRUE, time.inc = 24,design = dstr)

plot(nomogram(phmodel, fun = function(x)plogis(x),
                       funlabel='Predicted Risk at .... days ?'))
```

Answer (score 1):

With this type of model, the choice of time point prediction is up to you. There are no strata with potentially different baseline hazards over time, there are no time-dependent covariates, and I assume that the proportional hazards (PH) assumption is met, so the *hazard ratios* among different combinations of covariate values are the same at all times.

That of course doesn't mean that relative *survival* is the same at all times. So if your nomogram displays something related to survival (as I infer from your `plogis()` transformation) you should choose a time point that is generally accepted to be of practical interest in the field. For example in some types of cancer studies you might consider 3- or 5-year survival, with shorter or longer times for more or less aggressive forms of cancer.

The choice of a time point is *critical* when there are strata with different baseline hazards in the model, as can be done to overcome a failure of PH. Then again, the choice should be based on your knowledge of the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **EdM** for your answer about the choose of the time point.

For the code itself, I've finally found something like a slide presentation of the book of F. Harrell, made by himself and i've found the solution, written below. We have to declare the number of months in the cph function with time.inc =5*12 for 5 years for example (5 years of 12 months). Then create a 3 years time prediction for example as this : surv3<-function(x) surv(3*12,lp=x). And it works !
Here for a survival prediction for a median survival time, and for 3 and 5 years.

```
dd = datadist(data)
options(datadist='dd')
units(data$time_in_month)<- 'Month'

phmodel <- cph(Surv(time_in_month, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 , 
                   data=data,x=TRUE, y = TRUE, surv = TRUE, se.fit = TRUE,design = dstr, time.inc =5*12)

surv<-Survival(phmodel)
surv3<-function(x) surv(3*12,lp=x)
surv5<-function(x) surv(5*12,lp=x)
quan<-Quantile(phmodel)
med<-function(x) quan(lp=x)/12
ss<-c(.05 ,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7 ,.8,.9,.95)

nom <- nomogram(phmodel,fun=list(surv3 , surv5 , med),
              funlabel=c('3-year  Survival','5-year  Survival','Median Survival  Time (years)'),
              fun.at=list(ss, ss, c(.5 ,1:6)))

plot(nom, cex.var=1, cex.axis=.75, lmgp=.25)
```